# Restart a rake background task rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake-task, background-task

I have a rake task in a rails 4 application that is called from my controller and runs in background, like this:

```
system "rake fetch_news SOURCE=#{src} CATS=#{cat} C_ID=#{c_id} S_ID=#{s_id} FEED_ID=#{f_id} &"
```

It runs perfect in background, does it's job, but I need to start is again with same parameters, after a delay of 1.5 -- 2 minutes.

Informally, I see this like:

```
desc "Fetch news for specific category"
task :fetch_news => :environment do
    ... code of my background task ...
   sleep 120
   << insert here some code to restart the task >>
end
```

but I don't know how to implement this :(. Initially I thought I can define a function into my task, call the function, sleep, call it again, but the task doesn't permit to define a function into.

I searched on Google for solutions, but I don't find anything to help me. Can you give me an idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rake tasks you should use:

- CRON - in case if parameters is fixed. Look at [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) if you want to simplify work with CRON.
- [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) - in case if you want to change parameters in runtime. Sidekiq has ability to define [recurring jobs](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Scheduled-Jobs).

Comment: you can use both a rake task and cron -- execute the rake task with cron.You can also use ActiveJob in Rails4 (what the OP is already using) to set a job to be performed in the future -- you can't do reoccuring jobs, but you can possibly have a job that executes, and then sets another job to be performed in the future.  Only some ActiveJob adapters support future scheduled jobs. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html  And you could even have a cron job which runs every X minutes to executes a rake task to schedule an ActiveJob. I'd prob do it that way.